# C# mail sends only first attachment?

Tags: c#

Here `SmtpClient` sends the first file only as an attachment the rest I dont know. Is there should be some time to wait for the attachments send complately?

```
 private static void SendFiles()
 {
        var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("wmitask@gmail.com", "password");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress("wmitask@gmail.com");
        message.To.Add("wmitask@gmail.com");
        message.Subject = "File";
        message.Body = "Test";
        Attachment attachments = null;
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(programFilesDataDir))
        {
            attachments = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        }
        if (attachments == null)
            return;
        message.Attachments.Add(attachments);
        client.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: you need to move the `message.Attachments.Add` call into the loop.

Comment: ' Attachment data = new Attachment(attachments, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet); '
 ' message.attachments.Add(data); '

Comment: yeap sorry for my stupiduty :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(programFilesDataDir))` iteration, you are creating a new instance every time. So only the last attachment added will be retained.

Change the loop to add the attachment to `message.Attachments` within the `for....each` loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop you're assigning the `attachments` variable over and over for each attachment, in effect overriding what the value of the variable was before.

Try this:

```
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(programFilesDataDir))
    {
        attachments = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        message.Attachments.Add(attachments);           
    }
    if(attachments.Count > 0)
        client.Send(message);
```

But that means that you might create the whole message even if there are no files, and then never send it. If you only want to send a message if there are files then you can exit the method right away if there are no files. At the top of your method:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(programFilesDataDir);
if(files.Length) == 0 return;
```

And then after creating the message you can iterate over the `files` variable because you already know there are files.

```
    foreach (var file in files))
    {
        attachments = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
        message.Attachments.Add(attachments);           
    }
    client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add attachments you need to use :

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachTB.Text));
```

And if you want to add more call it again:

```
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachTB.Text));
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(AttachIITB.Text));
```